# Setting up a dev environment for OpenGL 4.2 on Linux (trouble sourcing gl.h)

Tags: c++, linux, opengl

I'm using GLFW and Netbeans to develop in C++. I'm able to render with immediate mode functions no problem. However, when I try to use core profile functions I get errors like this:

```
error: ‘glCreateShader’ was not declared in this scope
```

I get one of these errors for each core profile function I try. I did some research and found that GLFW doesn't provide any gl headers and just `#include`s the headers found on my system (at /usr/include/GL/).

Presumably this means that the gl.h and related files found here only contain the old style OpenGL API. I can't make sense of the hex code, but the gl.h file `#define`s GL_VERSION as 0x1F02.

If I perform this command in terminal: `glxinfo | grep -i opengl` it assures me that my OpenGL version string is "4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.88" -- Although I think that's reflected in the driver, unrelated to the gl.h file. Running this line in C++ code in my application yields the same string: `printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_VERSION));` For the same reason, no doubt.

Where can I source the appropriate OpenGL header files for OpenGL 3+ development on Ubuntu 13.04 x64?

I have installed these packages as suggested by most tutorials (to no avail): `xorg-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Never use the `#define`'d values in `gl.h` as if they mean anything. These are constant ID values that you use to query information from the OpenGL runtime, and the value of this **ID** will be the same across all implementations. In the case of `GL_VERSION`, you would do something like `glGetString (GL_VERSION)` in order to get the implementation-defined value for this.

Comment: Sometimes you could have 'gl2.h' header. Also you could use `#define GL_GLEXT_PROTOTYPES` and `#include <GL/glext.h>`. However, this will statically link you with used functions, so if they're not present - your program wouldn't even run. Please check Andon's answer about GLEW below, it contains important information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`glCreateShader (...)` is an OpenGL 2.0 function.

Short of OS X, I cannot think of any platforms that ship with OpenGL 2.0 without requiring runtime extension. On Microsoft Windows, you are guaranteed the full feature set of OpenGL 1.1 and anything beyond that requires calls to `wglGetProcAddress (...)` to load the function entry-points for the rest of the OpenGL API. The situation is the same on Linux, though it is more difficult to define what the "minimum" feature set is. In any case, to use `glCreateShader (...)` you are going to have to call `glXGetProcAddress (...)` in order to get the entry-point from the driver.

Libraries like GLEW will make your life easier by loading the entry-point for every function for each extension and core version of OpenGL your driver supports, on Ubuntu there should even be a package you can install that contains GLEW. Nevertheless, see the [official project site](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) for more details on actually using GLEW.

Comment: +1 for GLEW. GLee is a good loader too, but officially only supports up to OpenGL 3.0.

Comment: Just to make things clear - you don't really 'have to' use GetProcAddress. If you linked directly to functions, there is no need for that - you just can't execute your program if these functions aren't present on target machine. Because of extension-based nature of GL - it's best to use GetProcAddress because some program could change its flow depending of functionality present on target, but it is not really a requirement.

Comment: Also worth noting that GLEW have problems if you've created GL 4.0+ context (that's because glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) is no longer supported by 4.0, have to use glGetStringi() instead). Maybe they've already fixed this.

Comment: @keltar: That applies to OpenGL 3.2 core and beyond. I think you have to define the pre-processor token `GLEW_EXPERIMENTAL` to work-around that issue. It is kind of funny, when you think about it - `glGetStringi (...)` has to be loaded through the extension loading mechanism on most platforms, but to "correctly" query its existence you have to call it first. What GLEW should really use is a parameter at initialization-time indicating which context profile it is working under, none of this dumb pre-processor stuff :)

Comment: Ahh. That explains everything I needed, in just the right amount of detail. Thanks Andon. :D